# Does inserting and immediately removing a node change a red-black tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

I have the following problem:

> Does inserting a node into a red-black tree and then immediately deleting it always result in the original tree? Prove that it does or give a counter-example if it does not. Does deleting a leaf node from a red-black tree, then reinserting the same node always result in the original tree? Prove that it does or give a counter-example if it does not.

I have used several demos, but none of them have made much sense to answer this question. I havent been sure as to yes or no, I am still new to binary trees.

Comment: Try a few examples. If you find a counter-example, great. If not, try to prove it. If you get stuck, see if your attempts point at some counter-example. Repeat.

Comment: When you try a proof and get stuck, edit your question with that attempt so we can get you unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

It's not obvious that there is a "correct" answer to this question, as there are multiple insertion/deletion algorithms for red-black trees. Tarjan explicitly explains this in his book *Data Structures and Network Algorithms*, where he demonstrates (in section 4.2) update algorithms that require $O(1)$ rotations and references algorithms that require $\Omega(\lg n)$ rotations.

This is also mentioned in [Hize's "A Simple Implementation Technique for
Priority Search Queues"](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/ICFP01.pdf) and [Driscoll et al.'s "Making Data Structures Persistent"](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/making-data-structures-persistent.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the same node immediately after inserting will not always result in the original tree. As a counterexample, you can try inserting 4,7,10,23,5 (in this order). Now insert 65 and delete it. The tree before inserting 65 will be different from the tree after deleting 65. The reason is basically that if any property is violated in a RB treen then it rearranges itself to restore the property which changes its structure.

Comment: Considering jbapple's answer, which implementation does your example assume?